# OpenERP code throws exceptions when run in background

Tags: python, screen, locale, odoo, python-unicode

I don't know if this should be posted under serverfault or stackoverflow. I don't know if it's a locale problem on my server or if it's python or the OpenERP application that is acting up.

I have a OpenERP system and I have encountered a quite strange problem.

In the openERP modules there are some "print"-lines that various developers used for debugging the application.

Like these:

```
print "Value: %s" % variable
```

and

```
 print "Value: " + str(variable)
```

If I start OpenERP in a ordinary terminal it will run just fine in the foreground and print the debug log and the prints in the console. The application never gives me an exception.

**Now to the problem!**

Earlier I've started the application in a screen so that I could detach it and close my connection to the server while the application is till running.

The code does not throw any exception when run in a 'screen'

Instead of a screen I want to have init.d script. I've made this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Configuration variables for openerp
DAEMON="/opt/openerp-server-6.0.3/bin/openerp-server.py"
ARGS="--config=/opt/openerp-server-6.0.3/openerp-server.conf"
NAME="openerp"
USER="openerp"
DESC="openerp"
PIDFILE="/var/run/$NAME.pid"

# Startup alternatives
case "$1" in
        start)
                echo "Starting ${DESC}"
                start-stop-daemon --start --background --pidfile $PIDFILE --chuid $USER --make-pidfile --exec $DAEMON -- $ARGS
                ;;
        stop)
                echo "Stopping ${DESC}"
                start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile /var/run/${NAME}.pid --oknodo
                echo "${NAME}."
                ;;
        *)
                echo "Usage: start|stop"
        ;;
esac
```

The script works, it start and stops the server.

When I use the module that imports data from a excel file I get this exception. I also get the exception in other places in the code where it tries to print a string containing the swedish letters 'åäö'.

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in
>   position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

I thought it was something with the 'start-stop-daemon' command that changed the locale or somthing. So instead of forceing the application to the background with the argument '--background' I tried this:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile $PIDFILE --chuid $USER --make-pidfile --exec $DAEMON -- $ARGS &> /dev/null
```

This solved the UnicodeEncodeError. All joy I thought. But!

Now I get a Input/Output error

```
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

And the code that generates this

```
print pay_order
```

The 'pay_order' variable is a string that sometimes contain 'åäö'.

I can't understand why it behaves like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced the Unicode errors while using `print` for debugging errors similar to what you describe.

I think you should solve the problem at it's root: use `grep` to find the lines with `print` commands in the `addons`, and comment them out with `#`. The `print` command is never used in the standard modules.

Comment: You are correct, there should be no print in the module code. I'm doing a code review right now and removing "dirty code". Going to search for the solution why it behaves like this and post back later.

Comment: I have not found any solution yet for this problem. The only one so far is not to use 'print'.